# NIST fingerprint software terminal issue with Mac

Tags: terminal, fingerprint

I have been trying to get the NIST Biometric Image Software downloaded and running on a mac as I saw it would be easier than doing it on windows. I have it downloaded and have been trying to use the terminal to set it up, but it keeps saying it is unable to find it in the directory. I haven't worked with terminals much or anything of this magnitude. The input I am putting into the terminal is:

```
sh setup.sh <FINAL INSTALLATION DIR> [--without-X11]
```

With the final installation dir being the one I copied from the path where it is located. I am not sure if anyone has worked with this before, or had any similar issues to the one I have above. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am kind of lost on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open terminal then cd /Path /to/where/your/NISTsoftware/directory/is

Afterwards give it execute permussions by running this on terminal chmod 755 setup.sh

Then execute it so that you can install your NIST software by running ./setup.sh